# connect micromax A70 android phone to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently bought a new Micromax A70 & i'm trying to connect with my eclipse for android development to run my app directly by downloading the corresponding driver from [this link](http://techandwe.blogspot.com/2011/08/micromax-a70-usb-driver-and-connecting.html) & kept in following directory

```
D:\android-sdk_r06-windows\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\micromax_usb_driver
```

And also I followed the steps in [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#InstallingDriver). But still its not displaying in device of my eclipse.

Comment: [Check with this solution](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41076/micromax-a57-is-not-displayed-in-eclipse-device-list/44130#44130). Its working fine for me with Micromax Devices. Hope, this would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I found that, there's no digitally signed driver for Micromax Driver & Also the there's no official driver on Micromax official website.

So people don't buy Micromax mobiles for android development. And they are not at all stable.

Comment: Hello friend, I think I found solution for micromax a100, so I think you have to check it and reply to me as soon as possible. Then I will make some conclusion about the micromax devices. Because I want to purchase micromax a100. The following link contain device driver for a100. So I can use that device for development purpose or not        http://www.priceandspecification.in/micromax-a100-pc-suite-modem-driver-download.html

Comment: @Siddharth : Its a broken link.

Comment: If you want then I can help you to connect device with pc. For this pre requirement is linux os otherwise you have no scope to use micromax device.

Comment: Regarding "buy Micromax mobiles for android development", I just bought micromax canvas HD and it had device driver pre-packaged.

Comment: @Jameskittu you are wrong. I am using Micromax canvas a116 from last 2 years for android testing on linux platform. Works great for me.

Answer (score 6):

I am using micromax canvas HD A116. I have no problem for USB debugging with UBUNTU.

Follow below given instructions:

```
1) Go to Settings  > Developer options > check USB debugging in phone.

2) Connect the device.

3) Select media device(MTP) in The connect as dialogue.

4) Open terminal in Ubuntu(ctrl+alt+t) and type 'lsusb'.

5) Micromax will be connected as HTC and vendor id will 0bb4.

6) In terminal, login as root(sudo su) and type password.

7) Create a file: gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

8) In file, type: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

9) Save file and close it.

10) Now, execute that file: chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

11) Move to sdk/platform-tools: cd ~/sdk/platform-tools/ (specify the path where eclipse is present, before sdk, replace ~).

12) Type: a) adb kill-server(if its already running)
          b) adb start-server
          c) adb devices
13) Device come in list with a code and device like: 0000123355647 device

14) Now start eclipse and run your application, that device will show up.
```

Answer (score 3):

I got a micromax Canvas HD just for testing my android apps. I am using ubuntu 13.04.

This is what i did :

> 1) Settings > Developer options > check USB debugging
>
> 2) connect the device
>
> 3) SELECT media device(MTP) in The connect as dialogue

[image: Connect As]

**My /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file :**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

- the vendor id i'm using is of samsung but i tried a few others and they all seemed to work.
- the important thing was to have this line in the file because without it the device would not be recognized.

Comment: for my micromax A092, this doesn't work, i used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721922/get-vendor-id-of-android-powered-device-dynamically#answers-header to get idVendor of my phone

Answer (score 1):

I am using Micromax A70,
at begenning i was frustrated same like you.

but there is a solution for your problem;

Windows:
after installing the micromax A70 usb drivers (can be found in net or micromax service centers), in stall 91 PC suite (Chinese software for andoid sdk) and run the software which will then can be determined by eclipse and ADB commangs of android SDK.

LINUX:

1. Download android SDK (I compiled SDK from source for adb and fastboot) place all the bin files and executables and other java class librarirs in their respective system folders.
   (/usr/bin; /usr/lib ..etc)
2. create UDEV rules for you device as suggested in android documentation
3. and then sudo adb devices (you can see your devices listing)

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, finally I made my Micromax A57 to connect with eclipse and made it to suit for development.

1. Installed Moborobo (All in one Android smart phone management tool).
2. Perform stop -server / start -server using ADB.
3. Reboot the device.

   4.Restart the eclipse. Device got detected.(Eclipse - list of adb
   devices)

Answer (score 0):

I am using micromax canvas HD. I have no problem for USB debugging with UBUNTU.

Make sure that you have installed adb command using the following lines

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Before debugging using eclipse you need to initiate adb using sudo

```
sudo adb kill-server (if its already running)
sudo adb start-server
```

Ref [Install Adb](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/install-adb-and-fastboot-android-tools.html)

[Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to install any mobile driver in Ubuntu is as follows.

Install Synaptic packet manager from software center.

Search for MTP tools and install it.

After that connect your phone.

Turn on USB debugging from Developer options.

After that connect your phone.

Select MTP from the USB connection options.

There will be a popup asking to verify USB debugging.

Click Ok. DONE