# ?????? no permissions with Android development in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

I used this answer for fixing this problem - [set up device for development (?????? no permissions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions), and it has helped me. But there is the following problem - after rebooting the system I must execute the following commands:

```
sudo service udev restart
sudo killall adb
sudo ~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

After it all is good. But how can I fix it? I don't want to execute it each time after rebooting my system.

Comment: have you created a file named `51-android.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and added some lines to it

Answer (score 0):

First open terminal and enter `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and modify the file as shown below

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

PASSWORD='yourPasswordHere'

echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S service udev restart
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S killall adb
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S ~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server

exit 0
```

Now try `adb devices` after restarting your system. Make sure you replace `yourPasswordHere` with your login password. I haven't tested it. Hope this helps.