# Cannot connect phone to ADB for debugging

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

My environment -

- HTC Explorer with USB debugging turned on
- Ubuntu 12.10
- ADT 21
- Available targets - android-10, android-17

The output of `adb devices` on my system is -

```
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
????????????    no permissions
```

If the error message is to be believed it is a permissions issue. So I tried changing the permission of `/dev/sdb` to 777 but it did not work. (This is the device link that appears when I connect my phone)
In the past I have used windows to debug my applications on my phone so I'm confident that my phone supports USB debugging.

What is causing this problem?

Comment: You need to start `adb` with root right: `su -c 'adb start-server'`. Stop it first (if it is already running) by `adb stop-server`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me is do all the adb kill and start as a root. This would then detect the device!

If above doesnot work then try following
[set up device for development (?????? no permissions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

A year ago I was developing on Ubuntu and had this exact problem but unfortunately I can't positively remember how I was solving it. I think I was starting adb as a root for my SE phone to be connected...

Try this:

adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server