# unable to debug android/chrome remotely from ubuntu/linux

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I'm an android newbie. I've got a an android with chrome v30 installed. I enabled USB debugging on it. On my ubuntu linux I've installed ADB extension for chrome v27. I plug usb cable, so the connection is established automatically (ubuntu recognizes android as "camera"). On my laptop chrome I've got an android icon (ADB icon), I turn it on (start ADB). Then a number "1" shows up in a rectangle - yes, a device has been recognized (hurray!). But I'm unable to debug my mobile gmail. Either there is something wrong or I don't know how to access ADB. I've got following sections in the `View inspection targets`:

- Pages - these are just my laptop tabs
- Extensions - chrome laptop extensions, such as JSONView
- shared workers - empty
- other - with one element: chrome-devtools://devtools/devtools.html?dockSide=bottom&toolbarColor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=…

Does anyone know what did I do wrong? The chrome version on mobile is ok (should be 24+, it's 30), the USB debug permission is set to true, USB cable is plugged both ways, ADB icon shows `1`.

Besides, the official chrome ADB page says that I should run command `adb devices`, but I don't know where to execute it. I didn't install android SDK, since ADB is supposed to run without full android SDK installation. What is this command and how should I execute it?

Answer (score 19):

I have the same problem with you, you can follow the steps: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

you can type

`lsusb`

in your terminal to find your deveice's vendor id, 
then follow the steps above, finally, you may

`sudo service udev restart`

then restart adb , and you will see the device

Comment: a couple of months ago I followed this and somehow (I do not remember) managed chrome to work. But now I use notebook with fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 and for some reason can't make the same thing working. May be someone has the same problem, so please write in the comments

Comment: just have found the answer to my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions. A one needs to install adb and to run its server with root permissions `sudo adb start-server`

Comment: This helped me a little, after I connected my mobile I started my command prompt and typed: adb -status-window, it replied state unknown. After just reconnecting the device the fingerprint popped up and everything worked like a charm!

Comment: How do you 'restart' adb?

Answer (score 4):

- follow steps on https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#remote-debugging
- make sure USB debugging is enabled in Chrome as well (required before Chrome 32 ships)
- reconnect the device to see auth message on the device screen and accept it (Chrome 32 or Chrome Canary would list your device as pending auth unless you accept it)

Answer (score 2):

### Try enabling "PTP" mode on your device

On the device, in the notification for the cable connection, hit "Tap for more options" and select the "PTP" option.

This page specifically suggests this as one tip: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

More context:

- Initially, connecting my USB cable, and refreshing `chrome://inspect`, I got no prompt on the device or any changes in the PC browser.
- Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04
- Pixel 2 with latest Android OS I did not install any extra software
  (ADB or anything related to Android dev)
- Device was already working
  for remote dev on other systems (Macos)