# Android, Setup my Fairphone (FP1) for development, (?????? no permission)

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adb

I am running Eclipse v4.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.10.

I just received my Fairphone and wanted to start some simple and basic development (I am not an experienced Android developer).

For whatever reasons, adb did not recognise the FP1.

I then found the following workaround.

Enter the following commands:

```
adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server 
adb devices
```

After that, the FP1 did appear in the list of devices.
But, I don't understand why I had to do that.
With the Samsung Galaxy S Plus phone (stock rom and custom rom) I had before, I never had to run the adb server as root.
I assume running the adb server as root is only a workaround.

Does anybody know what could be real problem?
And the proper solution?

Comment: You need to setup the OS to allow device access for non-root users. See here for instructions: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html . To get the vendor ID just do a `lsusb`.

Comment: Thank you for your link his. I will try that.
For me it looks like that running the adb server as root once, solved the problem. I now no longer have to run the adb server as root.
But, I actually also created the 51-android.rules file as described in your link. I have to test which step (adb server as root, or 51-android.rules) solved the problem.
I will update my post, once I know for sure.

Comment: Why has this been closed? Once you have done it, could you please add the FP vendor ID as comment for future reference?

Comment: This has not yet beee closed. I will check again, and confirm how I got it working. Then I will report it back here. I assume I will be able to test it in the next days. Then I will report back.
Thank you his and Tiago Costa for your feedback so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to fairphone, as well as any other device just go to settings -> developper -> Turn on USB Debugging.

On linux you need to add to your 51.android-rules file, the USB driver for the device:
ATTR{idVendor}=="109b", ENV{adb_user}="yes"

its the same as the HTC USB property

You can also mess with the Fairphone OS, Peace of Mind, just download from the official GIT.

By the way, I was the lead developer for Fairphone during the last 8 months, great adventure, thanks for being one of the initial buyers.

Comment: Hi Tiago Costa. Thank you for your feedback. I will give it a try and report back, if this works for me. I got it working, but I have to confirm what which step I made really solved my connection problem.
I thank you for beeing a developer for the Fairphone. I like the phone and the project. Cheers Simon

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was:

- Activate USB Debugging on the Fairphone as described by Tiago Costa.
- Create a file "/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules" as described in http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up
- Then I restarted the adb server as described by Simon in his question (but **without** the sudo!)

However, the vendor ID Tiago Costa posted ("109b") did not work for me. It is also not the one associated with HTC (see http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds), which is "0bb4". For me, the latter one worked.

[Btw: One can easily find out the idVendor by using the terminal command "lsusb" to list the USB devices connected to the computer and then "lsusb -vs 005:013", where the first number is the Bus ID and the second the Device ID of "High Tech Computer Corp." (which is how the Fairphone is called in the list "lsusb" returned on my machine).]

Comment: Hi user3233963. Thank you for your feedback. I can confirm with the lsusb command, that my vendor ID of the FP1 is also not "109b", but "0bb4".
So according to the description (http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up) you are referring to, the correct line in the rules file would be the following.
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
But for some reason it still does not work for me running the adb-server without root (sudo) privileges.
I keep on testing and trying. You definitely helped me to move on. But the problem is not yet 100% solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the vendor id `109b`works.
I got the Fairphone recognized as written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9210397/364244

Comment: Hi dArignac. I will test, if the vendor id 109b works for me as well. Running adb as root works for me as well. But I consider that as a working workaround, but not a solution. Thank you for your comment.