# Logcat not working for ubuntu 14.04 android studio 0.8.2

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, logcat, galaxy

Logcat windows is completely empty. I have tried restarting it by hitting alt+6 a few times, I have disabled all filters, I have tried to change log levels to pretty much all available, I have tried killing adb server and restarting it again. Nothing helped.

I own galaxy s2 device with 4.1.2 jellybean installed on it. Developer mode and usb debugging is turned on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the device in the device list? Otherwise check answers there to get some possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions/9210397#9210397

Comment: @WarrenFaith yes, I do.

Comment: Have you selected the device in the list?

Comment: Log level at "Verbose"? Also tried to reselect the device itself? Do you see a list of processes on the left side?

Comment: @WarrenFaith I already mentioned that I have tried all log levels. I can see all services and I already did reselect the device itself.

Comment: than update to 0.8.4, restart device, AS and/or your pc. There is no valid reason that you can see the device and the process list but not the log. So the classy: "Have you tried to turn it off and on again"

Comment: you could also try to get the log directly via `adb shell logcat` and see if that works.

Comment: @WarrenFaith updates was unable to find anything newer then 0.8.2. I have tried to turn off studio completely and even reboot the pc. Didn't work.

Comment: Have you restarted the S2 as well? Change the update channel to "Canary Channel" in the update settings. Also verify that you have the latest android SDK stuff installed (build tools etc)

Comment: I did reboot S2.
I will try to update it to 0.8.4 later on, so I will report my progress later as well.
SDK's have been downloaded yesterday.

Comment: go to ddms,select your device in devices view and you should be able to see the logs

Answer (score 0):

The problem was custom rom that I was using for my galaxy s2 - NeatRom.

Comment: Next time you should inform us about a custom rom on the device :)