# fastboot and adb not working with sudo

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, sudo, fastboot

I have a very weird issue on my Ubuntu machine when trying to run the fastboot command.

When I run:

```
fastboot devices
```

I get

```
no permissions   fastboot
```

So I run the command with adminidtrator permissions:

```
sudo fastboot devices
```

And then I get the result

```
sudo: fastboot: command not found
```

How can this be? I have the directory in my PATH and everything works correctly without sudo.

Comment: chmod +x? 5 more to go...I'm done.

Comment: single `udev` rule to take care of all `adb` and `fastboot` devices at once https://stackoverflow.com/a/45006231/1778421

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Instead of forcing permissions via `sudo` each time you need to run `fastboot`, you can permanently fix the issue:

1. use `lsusb` to identify your device USB VendorID
2. configure `udev` to set proper permissions when your device is plugged in
3. profit!

As a bonus - it  will be fixed for `adb` too.

For example, in my case (for 'Megafon SP-A20i') :

```
$ fastboot devices
no permissions  fastboot
$ sudo fastboot devices
[sudo] password for kaa: 
MedfieldA9055F28    fastboot
$
```

Let's fix:

First, we need to identify the device:

a) look for usb bus number (hack: I know the device is Intel-based one)

```
$ fastboot -l devices
no permissions         fastboot usb:1-1.2
$ lsusb |grep 001 |grep -i intel
Bus 001 Device 044: ID 8087:09ef Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
$
```

b) look for other Intel devices:

```
$ lsusb |grep 8087
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 044: ID 8087:09ef Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
$
```

Hubs are not smartphones definetely, so - USB vendorID we need is "8087".

Second, configure `udev` (you must replace "idVendor" value with yours) :

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo '# Megafon SP-A20i' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules"
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'SUBSYSTEM==\"usb\", ATTR{idVendor}==\"8087\", MODE=\"0666\", GROUP=\"plugdev\"' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules"
$ sudo service udev restart
udev stop/waiting
udev  start/running, process 1821
$
```

Third, re-plug your device to allow `udev` to perform it's magic.

Final check:

```
$ fastboot -l devices
MedfieldA9055F28       fastboot usb:1-1.2
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 

$ fastboot reboot
rebooting...

finished. total time: 0.253s
$ sleep 90
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
MedfieldA9055F28    device

$
```

Voila!

Comment: Thanks this worked, but the line with   "lsusb |grep 001 |grep -i intel" messed me up because i was trying to add a nexus 5x phone which is a google phone.  So I omitted the "|grep -i intel" part and used "lsusb | grep 001" only and it gave me a full list that showed my nexus 5x device. 

'Bus 001 Device 015: ID 18d1:d00d Google Inc."

I then used 18d1 in place of 8087 and it worked

Answer (score 10):

You can use

> sudo $(which fastboot) devices

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. How can I fix this though? To work normally as "sudo fastboot devices"?

Comment: Please don't use sudo as an answer. running as root is really bad if it isn't necessary.

Comment: `sudo` is an impersonation of root, not root.  If they advocated `su` then I could see your point.  `sudo` is the way almost all commands are run in Linux, not sure what the obsession is with not using it for fastboot..

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is your system version is too old,for example ,my system Version is ubuntu 20.10 but after i do these command it works.
1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get upgrade
3. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
4. sudo apt-get install android-tools-fastboot
then reboot fastboot Or reboot your devices.
^ ^

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a command using sudo, it's not using your current user profile paths, but the sudoers secure path.

You can edit the secure paths with the following command:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

and add your path here :

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/your/path/here"
```