# Android Studio issue running app on device (minSdk)

Tags: android

I am attempting to run an app on a device.  When I run the app, however, I get this:

Compatible No  MinSdk(API 19)>deviceSdk(API1)

Why is this?  Why is my device API 1?

Thanks so much for help.

Comment: whats the device u r running the app? what are the settings set on the manifest?

Comment: Device is Samsung Galaxy S4, brand new.

Comment: I set min device to be API19

Comment: and all the permissions are activated on the device? to allow installation of unsigned apps

Comment: Wasn't aware I needed to do allow installation of unsigned apps...let me look into how to do that..thanks!

Comment: I noticed `???????????? no permissions` after running `adb devices`. [This grebulon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions) solved my issue.
Just for the record: I'd navigated to the developer options page and selected "Revoke USB debugging authorization" before. There's a good overview on the offical [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) manual.