# USB debugging in lava-iris

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, smartphone, usb-debugging

I am developing a mobile app in android studio in ubuntu.To run my app in my mobile(lava iris) I have enabled developer option and also usb debugging options.When I try to run my app in the running device

I could see that it shows the following details as

device                 serialnumber
???????????[null]       ?????????
I have also attached the screen shot of those details
I have also included /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules   file also
But also I couldn't run my app in my mobile[image: I have also attached the screen shot of those details] 
what should I do now to run my app in the running device?.I have also seen other questions similar usb debugging problems but they didn't match with my question.

Comment: What are the VID & PID of your device?  Show the line from the udev rules file which you think will handle this.  Did you reboot or tell udev to reload its rules and then replug the device after adding that?

Comment: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idvendor}=="0502", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"      is my udev rules.Is there any problem with this udev rule?

Comment: What is the VID of your phone shown by `lsusb` ?

Comment: Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bb4:0c03 High Tech Computer Corp.

Comment: That 0bb4 VID doesn't match your quoted udev rule's 0502.

Comment: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idvendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"    I have changed that also,but still I am getting the same details as shown above.what is wrong in that?

Comment: @chris stratton when I try "adb devices" i could get" List of devices attached 
???????????? no permissions"
ls -l /dev/bus/usb/002/007    gives me     crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 134 May  4 15:25 /dev/bus/usb/002/007.I have also included adb's path in .bashrc  i have tried all the possible solution as mentioned in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions   But nothing works.

Comment: Thank you.It worked after rebooting the system twice.