# ADB | Having troubles with device connection

Tags: android, linux, adb, cyanogenmod

I am working flashing a custom ROM on a new device. Through a bit of research, I've found that I am able to completely circumvent the need to port Clockworkmod by simply using UniFlash on my Windows based laptop. From there, I am left with needing to port the ROM I desire, Cyanogenmod 12, to my device.

I've come to learn that I do not need to build from source, rather I can tailor an existing recovery to fit my device. I am unsure if that is true, so that may need to be cleared up. I went ahead and installed ADB and found a porting guide on the Cyanogenmod Wiki. This is where I am running into problems. I do not seem to have ADB permissions for my device.

When attempting to grab my build.prop, I get this return:

```
user@mypc:~$ adb pull /system/build.prop
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: insufficient permissions for device
```

After realizing my computer may not see the device, I tried to see which were connected:

```
user@mypc:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

It seems I do not have any access to the device at all. USB Debugging is connected, it is a rooted device, and it is set show as a USB Storage. I'm sure if I can at least get this fixed, I should be able to find my way through the rest of the guide myself.

Thank you for any help I can receive!

EDIT 01-

So, I decided to do more digging, and I guess I needed to START the server as super user, and not just run commands in super user.

After running this command, I was able to use my others with permission:
    user@mypc:~$ sudo adb start-server

Now, I am running into a problem in which my device is offline:

```
user@mypc:~$ adb pull /system/build.prop
error: device offline
```

After referring to this ([set up device for development (?????? no permissions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions)) thread, I seem to get a new response:

```
user@mypc:~$ adb pull /system/build.prop
error: device not found
```

I feel it's safe to say I should remove 51-android.rules from my ~/rules.d/.

Edit 02:

It seems I have answered my own question with research. I guess I just needed to update to the newest version because Android 4.2+ requires bridge authorization to complete tasks, and my version did not know to do that! I was successfully able to pull my build.prop!

Comment: even i used to have the same issue. then i have tried by selecting the adb device from the DDMS solved my issue...........

Comment: As a friendly note @Methamphetadreams, this is a Q and A site. You will get more help if you stick to asking direct questions without adding lots of back-story that is completely unrelated to what you are trying to solve. Hence my rather brutal edit of your question, sorry.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Try restarting the adb server on your pc with sudo.

Comment: I did fix the problem using @hoomi 's answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that when you connect the USB device it shows a popup asking if you want to allow your pc access the device. You have to accept that manually from the device.

Something like this

http://www.gihosoft.com/android-recovery/img/allow-usb-debugging.png

Comment: I wish I would have looked at this a bit before my research because you were totally correct! I found this through many links, and your answer would have lead me much quicker. Thank you!

Comment: Now, to begin my long journey of porting this ROM. v.v

Comment: Can you make this as your answer? :)

Comment: Done! I hope that helps your reputation go up! I'm unsure who marked it down.