# Get Vendor ID of Android powered device dynamically

Tags: android

I want to get the `Vendor ID` of my Android Device through my code.

I have read this: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html, but it does not tell you how to retrieve it through code.

I have even searched in `android.os.Build.<attributes>` but none of them gives the `VendorID`.

Can any one tell me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are running Ubuntu/Linux just type in terminal `lsusb -v` and press enter.
It will bring out details of all USB devices.
Check for a field called `idVendor` in the results and find your device.

E.g. my Motorola Defy (vendor id = 22b8) gives:

```
idVendor           0x22b8 Motorola PCS
```

Comment: Neat solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

may be [android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER) is what you are looking for..

There is also one more field called brand [android.os.Build.BRAND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#BRAND) which specify The brand (e.g., carrier) the software is customized for, if any.

You can also try our [Phone Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sysinfo.sysinfo.sysinfo) app from app store to check these value on your device.

Comment: The android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER returns the manufacturer of the product/hardware. Will it return ID or the name? And also what android.os.Build.BRAND returns?

Comment: On My samsung Galalxy S International Version both these values return samsung

Comment: I have added reference to an app that can be used to check these value on device..

Comment: But I want the vendor ID, are you retrieving the vendor ID in your app? How can I get it?

Comment: Please tell me what do you mean by vendor.

Comment: The link talks about setting up device for development on Ubuntu and it also talks about setting up USB configuration for each type of device you want to set up for development. it also provide list of vendor ids that can be used for setting up the configuration. following is the link to the vendor ids http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds. Please tell me what is use case you are trying to implement in your application.

Comment: Android also has a package for USB http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html. This would help you getting more info about USB related API in android.

Comment: Thanks Praful. Right now, I am working on other things as well. If you are available after, say 1 hour or so, we'll figure out the solution on same. Will you be available? And thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: Just sent the chat invite by mistake. Please post your progress on this thread and I would try to help on it..