# usb debugging with micromax unit a092 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, adb, usb-debugging

I am using Micromax Unite A092, for USB debugging in Ubuntu 12.04. I enabled "USB debugging" from developer options and "connected as a media device".
But `./adb devices` does not show it.

I tried
`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7f10", MODE="0666"` writing in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` but no luck.

The output of `lsusb` is-

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 036: ID 1c9e:7f10 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY 
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3bb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
```

could you please guide me.
This time I am following 
[connect micromax A70 android phone to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831537/connect-micromax-a70-android-phone-to-eclipse)

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your USB Vendor ID to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`:

```
echo "0x1c9e" >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

and restart `adb`:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe its working. perfect. Thanks a lot, you made me developer